# Как поменять иконки, которые выводятся через Fonts на иконки .png?

Tags: html, css, css3

Есть вертикальное [**меню**](http://codepen.io/geoffyuen/pen/szAhu), в котором все иконки выводятся через шрифт (`Fonts`). Как поменять, иконки в меню на обычные картинки в формате `.png`.

Html:

```
<nav id="site-nav" class="site-nav" role='navigation'>
  <button href="#" id="site-nav--toggle"  class="site-nav--toggle"><i class="entypo-menu"></i>Menu</button></button>
  <ul class="site-nav--list">
    <li><a href="#"><i class="entypo-gauge"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="entypo-download"></i>Work Queue</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="entypo-picture"></i>Asset Mgmt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="entypo-doc-text"></i>Reports</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="entypo-chart-bar"></i>Admin</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="entypo-user"></i>Your Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="entypo-logout"></i>Logout</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="entypo-lifebuoy"></i>Help</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Удали все шрифты и сделал через  `background:url('menu.png') no-repeat ;`

Answer (score 1):

А что мешает просто `img src` поставить?

Например, вместо

```
<a href="#"><i class="entypo-gauge"></i>Dashboard</a>
```

поставить

```
<a href="#"><img src="dashboard.php" alt="Dashboard"></a>
```

Comment: а цвет изображения при hoverе как будет меняться в этом случае? может лучше через псевдоэлементы это сделать, ввиде спрайта

Comment: Цвет изображения меняться просто так не будет. Вопрос-то был про картинку png :) Но так, чтобы менялся цвет - тут вариантов много. Все зависит от желания разработчика :) Можно два png сделать и переключать в css. Можно svg поставить. Можно сделать прозрачный png и просто менять фон... По желанию. Вариантов полно... Вплоть до анимации :):):):):):)